# Dynamically create svg group clones which is store in a variable using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

i have a lot shapes created using svg tags and which in turn stored in js variables . I want to  clone and append the groups to svg element with unique ids using js.

```
var ped_pb = '<g transform="scale(1.5)" stroke-width=".0005"><path i:knockout="Off" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.411,0.506V13.17h12.697V0.506H10.411z"/><g> <defs><path id="XMLID_1_" d="M0,0.253h23.87v23.809H0V0.253z"/>                        </defs>                     <clipPath id="XMLID_2_"><use xlink:href="#XMLID_1_" /></clipPath><path i:knockout="Off" clip-path="url(#XMLID_2_)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0131" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="M10.411,0.506h12.697V13.17H10.411V0.506z"/></g><g stroke-width=".000000000000000000005"><path i:knockout="Off" clip-path="url(#XMLID_4_)" stroke="#000000"  stroke-width="0.0317" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1.523,23.777l7.555-8.422l-1.523-1.361l-7.523,8.422L1.523,23.777zM7.904,21.782l1.777-8.611l-8.38,2.723c-0.54,0.158-0.825,0.729-0.667,1.267c0.19,0.538,0.762,0.823,1.301,0.665l6.698-2.185l-1.301-1.172l-1.429,6.902c-0.095,0.538,0.254,1.076,0.794,1.203C7.269,22.668,7.777,22.321,7.904,21.782z"/></g></g>';
```

i need a js function to populate the above shapes stored in variable to an svg element in different x or y coordinates as when required.

Comment: i have achieved the goal in some how

Answer (score -1):

i have achieved the goal in the following way

```js
var ped_pb = '<g transform="scale(1.5)" stroke-width=".0005" style="border: 1px dashed black;"><path i:knockout="Off" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.411,0.506V13.17h12.697V0.506H10.411z"/><g> <defs><path id="XMLID_1_" d="M0,0.253h23.87v23.809H0V0.253z"/>      </defs>      <clipPath id="XMLID_2_"><use xlink:href="#XMLID_1_" /></clipPath><path i:knockout="Off" clip-path="url(#XMLID_2_)" fill="none"  stroke-width="1.0131" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="M10.411,0.506h12.697V13.17H10.411V0.506z"/></g><g stroke-width=".000000000000000000005"><path i:knockout="Off" clip-path="url(#XMLID_4_)"   stroke-width="0.0317" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1.523,23.777l7.555-8.422l-1.523-1.361l-7.523,8.422L1.523,23.777zM7.904,21.782l1.777-8.611l-8.38,2.723c-0.54,0.158-0.825,0.729-0.667,1.267c0.19,0.538,0.762,0.823,1.301,0.665l6.698-2.185l-1.301-1.172l-1.429,6.902c-0.095,0.538,0.254,1.076,0.794,1.203C7.269,22.668,7.777,22.321,7.904,21.782z"/></g></g>';
function clone(){

 
 var element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'lk');
 element.innerHTML= ped_pb;
 gg.appendChild(element)
 
 element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'lk1');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate(40,80)');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#0FF');
 element.innerHTML= ped_pb;
 gg.appendChild(element)
 
 
 element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'lk2');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'translate(80,120)');
 element.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#f00');
 element.innerHTML= ped_pb;
 gg.appendChild(element)
}

  document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
            function init()
            {
                //clone()
    clone()
                }
```

```html
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<g id="gg">
<path id="pawn" d="M 22 9 C 19.792 9 18 10.792 18 13 C 18 13.885103 18.29397 14.712226 18.78125 15.375 C 16.829274 16.496917 15.5 18.588492 15.5 21 C 15.5 23.033947 16.442042 24.839082 17.90625 26.03125 C 14.907101 27.08912 10.5 31.578049 10.5 39.5 L 33.5 39.5 C 33.5 31.578049 29.092899 27.08912 26.09375 26.03125 C 27.557958 24.839082 28.5 23.033948 28.5 21 C 28.5 18.588492 27.170726 16.496917 25.21875 15.375 C 25.70603 14.712226 26 13.885103 26 13 C 26 10.792 24.208 9 22 9 z " />
</g>
</svg>
```